Product delaits information is not showing in react js
I have linked a page through id, but it doesnt seems to appear that means it cant read the id passed through useparams, what is the problem in the code? could anyoone help me?
Here is the code for individual details calling through id
const TourDetails = () => {

   const {id} = useParams();
   const reviewMsgRef = useRef('')
   const [tourRating, setTourRating]=useState(null)

   const tour = tourData.find(tour=>tour.id === id);

   const { photo, title, desc, price, address, reviews, city, distance, maxGroupSize } = tour;

   const {totalRating, avgRating}= calculateAvgRating(reviews);

   //formate date

   const options = {day:'numeric', month:'long', year:"numeric"};

   //submit rqst to the server

   const submitHandler = e=>{

    e.preventDefault()
    const reviewText = reviewMsgRef.current.value;
 
    alert('${reviewText}, ${tourRating}');
    // later will call api

   }

  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col lg="8">
              <div className="tour__content">
                <img src={photo} alt="" />

                <div className="tour__info">
                  <h2>{title}</h2>

                  <div className="d-flex align-items-center gap-5">
                  <span className="tour__rating d-flex align-items-center gap-1">
            <i class="ri-star-fill" style={{'color':"var(--secondary-color)"}}></i> {avgRating === 0? null: avgRating} 
            {totalRating === 0? 'Not Rated' : <span>({reviews.length})</span>}
            
        </span>

        <span>
          <i class="ri-map-pin-user-fill"></i> {address}
        </span>
                  </div>

                  <div className="tour__extra-details">
                    <span><i class="ri-map-pin-2-line"></i>{city}</span>
                    <span><i class="ri-money-dollar-circle-line"></i>${price}/ per person</span>
                    <span><i class="ri-map-pin-time-line"></i>{distance} k/m  </span>
                    <span><i class="ri-group-line"></i>{maxGroupSize} people</span>
  
                  </div>
                  <h5>Description</h5>
                  <p>{desc}</p>
                </div>

                {/* tour review section*/}
                <div className="tour__reviews mt-4">
                  <h4>Reviews ({reviews?.length} reviews)</h4>
            
                <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                  <div className="d-flex align-items-center gap-3 mb-4 rating__group"> 
                  
                  <span onClick={()=>setTourRating(1)}>1<i class="ri-star-s-fill"></i></span>
                  <span onClick={()=>setTourRating(2)}>2<i class="ri-star-s-fill"></i></span>
                  <span onClick={()=>setTourRating(3)}> 3<i class="ri-star-s-fill"></i></span>
                  <span onClick={()=>setTourRating(4)}>4<i class="ri-star-s-fill"></i></span>
                  <span onClick={()=>setTourRating(5)}>5<i class="ri-star-s-fill"></i></span>
                  
                  </div>

                  <div className="review__input">
                    <input type="text" ref={reviewMsgRef} placeholder="share your thoughts" required/>
                    <button className="btn primary__btn text-white" type="submit">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </Form>
                <ListGroup className="user__reviews">
                 
                 {
                  reviews?.map(reviews=>(
                    <div className="review__item">
                      <img src={avatar} alt=""/>

                      <div className="w-100">
                        <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                          <div>
                            <h5>Muhib</h5>
                            <p>{new Date('01-18-2024').toLocaleDateString("en-US", options )}</p>
                          </div>
                          <span className="d-flex align-items-center">
                            5<i class="ri-star-s-fill"></i>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                        <h6>Amazing Tour</h6>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ))
                 }

                </ListGroup>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Col>
            <col lg='4'>
              <Booking tour={tour} avgRating={avgRating}/>
            </col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </section>
      <Newsletter />
    </>
  );
};

export default TourDetails;


and here is the code from where it will link to individual page
const TourCard = ({tour}) => {

 
  const{id, title, city, photo, price, featured, reviews } = tour;
   
    const{totalRating, avgRating}= calculateAvgRating(reviews)

  return (
    <>
    <div className="tour__card">
      <Card>
        <div className="tour__img">
            <img src={photo} alt="tour-img"/>
            {featured && <span>Featured</span>}
        </div>
      </Card>

        <CardBody>
        <div className="card__top d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <span className="tour__location d-flex align-items-center gap-1">
            <i class="ri-map-pin-line"></i> {city}
        </span>
        <span className="tour__rating d-flex align-items-center gap-1">
            <i class="ri-star-fill"></i> {avgRating === 0? null: avgRating} 
            {totalRating === 0? ( 'Not Rated' ): <span>({reviews.length})</span>}
            
        </span>
        </div>

        <h5 className="tour__title">
          <Link to={`/tours/${id}/`}>{title}</Link>
          </h5> 

        <div className="card__bottom d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-3">
            <h5>${price}<span>/ per person</span></h5>
            
            <button className='btn booking__btn'>
            <Link to={`/tours/${id}/`}>Book Now</Link>
            </button>

        </div>
      </CardBody>
     
     
    </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TourCard;

used this to link the products details, but when i go through this link, it shows blank
{title} 
i`m expecting that, i could the tour details page as per as their tour id

Remove the last "/" from the route? /tours/${id}

didn`t work,applied but still same

const Routers = () => {
return (

<Route path='/' element={}/>
<Route path = '/home' element={} />
<Route path = '/tours' element={} />
<Route path = '/tours/:id' element={} />
<Route path = '/login' element={} />
<Route path = '/register' element={} />
<Route path = '/thank-you' element={} />
<Route path = '/tours/search' element={} />

);
};
export default Routers;

Use this format for path: /tours/:id/

same, not working

From where is tourData coming? const tour = tourData.find(tour=>tour.id === id);

yes, from this file, tour.js

this file,  @natashap
const tours = [
{
id: "01",
title: "Westminister Bridge",
city: "London",
distance: 300,
price: 99,
address: 'Somewhere',
maxGroupSize: 10,
desc: "this is the description",
reviews: [
{
name: "jhon doe",
rating: 4.6,
},
],
avgRating: 4.5,
photo: tourImg01,
featured: true,
}
export default tours;
